# Java Jar files not executing

Tags: java, jar

Not too long ago I asked a question about distribution of java jar files...that was perfectly answered and my jar files were completely working fine...but in a past few days they have stopped working directly by double clicking and i have to run it through the command java -jar .jar
what could be the possible reason behind this...i mean i have already included the manifest file and the main classes have also been defined.... I have really no idea whats going on here!!
previously asked question
[Distributing java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297603/distributing-java-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it works with `java -jar ...`, it can be safely assumed that `java` can be accessed via the classpath.

Check that the .jar file type is still associated with Java. How to do this depends on your operating system.

If this doesn't work, try [Jarfix](http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html). It helped me once with exactly the same problem.

PS: Jarfix works only on Windows.

Comment: Jarfix worked fine..but still i have no clue what happened!! Will u care to elaborate.

Comment: @AnirudhChhangani My best guess is that you updated Java (manually or automatically) and that might have screwed up something. I honestly can not give a more precise answer because that would be just guessing (which is worthless). I'm glad it worked, though :) .